# Looking for a sci fi story from the 60's or 70's in which an ancient robot army is activated

Tags: story-identification

I have searched high and low for this story which I remember reading as a kid. The story involves a robot army which was built thousands of years before the time of the story's events, - during a war - as the ultimate deterrent. It's existence has been forgotten but is hinted at in ancient documents which keep referring to a phrase something like "the legions of night will come at the end"

Millennia later the army is activated - but heads off in the wrong direction because the intended target, which was the enemy's capital city, has moved in the intervening years.

Comment: sounds similar to Hellboy 2 The Golden Army - it's certainly not, but since a good chunk of that universe comes from existing mythologies, etc...there might be an out-of-universe, production interview or some such that indicates a common source

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[The Regiments of Night](http://www.apocalypsebooks.com/books/regiments-night/)* by Brian N. Ball

[image]

> **Synopsis**
> A dead empire's vengeance can wait a thousand years!
>
> Beneath the Earth's shattered crust... does the black army still wait? After a thousand years of defeat... Is the Black Army still fit? Inside their lost underground stronghold... is the Black Army drilling?
>
> Archeologists considered the legend superstition and poked about among the surface ruins. Tourists regarded the tales as tourism ads to glamorize a burned-out world. Robots believed only what they saw and none had ever seen such an army. But when a combination of all three tripped the alarm by accident, they found reality turned suddenly into nightmare... as the Black Army awoke to march against the universe!
>
> **Excerpt**
> "Their crest," the Revived Man said, pointing to the ruins below. "The crest of the second interplanetary confederation."
>
> In spite of the passing of centuries it had survived. Three sunbursts still glowed along one intact radiation shield, the proud emblem of the ancient Empire.
>
> "One for each of the planets they held," said the Brigadier.
>
> "They ruined this one," Khalia siad. "See what it says about the legend." She felt the cold edge of menace.
>
> The Brigadier read out the words with a connoisseur's pride. "Powerful words! Listen! It's just a line, but it's survived for a thousand years. A promise and a threat: "The Regiments of Night shall come at the end."